Automate % score on SharePoint when answer are text
I have a list when has various column with choice based answers (Yes, Partial, No, N/A)
I would like the last column to display a overall $score.
However when I use the following JSON view format it displays the code in the column rather then the % score.
Any assistance is very much appreciated.

{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=ceiling(((if([$Incident details]=='Yes',2,if([$Incident details]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Patient details]=='Yes',2,if([$Patient details]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Consent & capacity]=='Yes',2,if([$Consent & capacity]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Presenting complaint]=='Yes',2,if([$Presenting complaint]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Primary survey]=='Yes',2,if([$Primary survey]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$FAST status]=='Yes',2,if([$FAST status]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Medical history]=='Yes',2,if([$Medical history]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Secondary survey]=='Yes',2,if([$Secondary survey]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Observations]=='Yes',2,if([$Observations]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Treatment]=='Yes',2,if([$Treatment]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Resuscitation]=='Yes',2,if([$Resuscitation]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Vehicle times]=='Yes',2,if([$Vehicle times]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Medication given]=='Yes',2,if([$Medication given]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Additional notes]=='Yes',2,if([$Additional notes]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Handling & immobilisation]=='Yes',2,if([$Handling & immobilisation]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Discharge]=='Yes',2,if([$Discharge]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Declined treatment]=='Yes',2,if([$Declined treatment]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Outcome]=='Yes',2,if([$Outcome]=='Partial',1,0))+if([$Treated by]=='Yes',2,if([$Treated by]=='Partial',1,0))))/(2+if([$Incident details]=='N/A',2)+if([$Patient details]=='N/A',2)+if([$Consent & capacity]=='N/A',2)+if([$Presenting complaint]=='N/A',2)+if([$Primary survey]=='N/A',2)+if([$FAST status]=='N/A',2)+if([$Medical history]=='N/A',2)+if([$Secondary survey]=='N/A',2)+if([$Observations]=='N/A',2)+if([$Treatment]=='N/A',2)+if([$Resuscitation]=='N/A',2)+if([$Vehicle times]=='N/A',2)+if([$Medication given]=='N/A',2)+if([$Additional notes]=='N/A',2)+if([$Handling & immobilisation]=='N/A',2)+if([$Discharge]=='N/A',2)+if([$Declined treatment]=='N/A',2)+if([$Outcome]=='N/A',2)+if([$Treated by]=='N/A',2)))*100) + '%'"
}


Make sure you are:

Using correct internal names of your columns in JSON. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?
Closing each if function with <false-value> parameter (if function requires total 3 parameters). Syntax: if(<condition>, <true-value>, <false-value>)

Try using this JSON formatting code once for your scenario:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=ceiling((if([$Incident details]=='Yes',2,if([$Incident details]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Patient details]=='Yes',2,if([$Patient details]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Consent & capacity]=='Yes',2,if([$Consent & capacity]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Presenting complaint]=='Yes',2,if([$Presenting complaint]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Primary survey]=='Yes',2,if([$Primary survey]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$FAST status]=='Yes',2,if([$FAST status]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Medical history]=='Yes',2,if([$Medical history]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Secondary survey]=='Yes',2,if([$Secondary survey]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Observations]=='Yes',2,if([$Observations]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Treatment]=='Yes',2,if([$Treatment]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Resuscitation]=='Yes',2,if([$Resuscitation]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Vehicle times]=='Yes',2,if([$Vehicle times]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Medication given]=='Yes',2,if([$Medication given]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Additional notes]=='Yes',2,if([$Additional notes]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Handling & immobilisation]=='Yes',2,if([$Handling & immobilisation]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Discharge]=='Yes',2,if([$Discharge]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Declined treatment]=='Yes',2,if([$Declined treatment]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Outcome]=='Yes',2,if([$Outcome]=='Partial',1,0)) + if([$Treated by]=='Yes',2,if([$Treated by]=='Partial',1,0)))/(2+ if([$Incident details]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Patient details]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Consent & capacity]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Presenting complaint]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Primary survey]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$FAST status]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Medical history]=='N/A',2,0) +if([$Secondary survey]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Observations]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Treatment]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Resuscitation]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Vehicle times]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Medication given]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Additional notes]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Handling & immobilisation]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Discharge]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Declined treatment]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Outcome]=='N/A',2,0) + if([$Treated by]=='N/A',2,0)))*100 + '%'"
}

